# How to load html content in ScriptEditorWebpart in modern Sharepoint page using OfficeDevPnP?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, spfx, officedev

I have added ScriptEditorWebpart in modern Sharepoint page using C# code. Now I want to load html content in ScriptEditorWebpart and Save by C# code using OfficeDevPnP. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Pages library, create a classic page. Click Edit Source in the ribbon and add the code. Only way you can do this OTB is by saving your HTML code as a . aspx page, uploading it into a document library and then using the 'Embed' webpart.

If that doesn't work, this video might help you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhKwWgILv_Y

I believe this should help, if I understand your problem correctly